# Can I use the mapping notation to describe this vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, linear-transformations

So, I recently learned that the statement $v \in \mathbf F^S$, where $\mathbf F$ is a field and $S$ is a set, can be rewritten as  $v : S \rightarrow \mathbf F$.

Does this imply that $ x\in \mathbf F^n$ can be rewritten as $x: n\rightarrow \mathbf F$?

$x$ is a mapping of $ n $ onto $ \mathbf F$?

Comment: $x$ is a mapping of $\{1,\dots, n\}$ into $F$. So, the tuple $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ is identified with the function ($x_1=x(1),\dots, x_n=x(n)$).

Answer (score 1):

As @peek-a-boo pointed out,  there's a way to.  The caveat is that $n$ refers to an $n$ element set.

Then the vector space $\Bbb F^n$ can then be considered as the space of functions from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $\Bbb F$.

This is a sort of *functional analysis* approach.